Laravel: Missing required parameter for [Route: cicilan] [URI: cicilan/{id}] [Missing parameter: id]
I'm trying to open cicilan page while passing the id where the button is clicked then show the data based on the id. this is the cicilan button
data: 'statusPelunasan',
name: 'statusPelunasan',
render: function (data, type, row) {
if (row.statusPelunasan === 0 && row.status === 0) {
   return '<strong style="color: #BFBF00;">Belum Diterima</strong>';
}else if (row.statusPelunasan === 0 && row.status === 1) {
   return '<a class="btn btn-info cicilanBtn" href="{{ route("cicilan", ":id") }}">'.replace(':id', row.idPengajuan) + 'Cicilan</a>';
}else if (row.statusPelunasan === 1 && row.status === 1) {
   return '<strong style="color: green;">Lunas</strong>';
}else{
   return '';
}}

this is my route
Route::get('/cicilan/{id}', [CustomController::class, 'cicilan'])->middleware('isLoggedIn')->name('cicilan');

and this is my controller
public function cicilan(Request $request, $id)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $data = Cicilan::where('idPengajuan', $id)->select('*');
        Log::info($data->get());
        return Datatables::of($data)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->make(true);
    }
    $userId = $request->session()->get('loginId');
    $user = Anggotakoperasi::find($userId);
    $status = $user ? $user->status : null;
    $navbarItems = Navbar::all();
    $accessibleFeatures = KontrolAkses::where('status', $status)
        ->pluck('idFitur')
        ->toArray();
    return view('cicilan', ['status' => $status, 'navbarItems' => $navbarItems, 'accessibleFeatures' => $accessibleFeatures]);

}

i've tried various way but the end it always show Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException
Missing required parameter for [Route: cicilan] [URI: cicilan/{id}] [Missing parameter: id]. (View: C:\Users\Me\Documents\GitHub\skripsiWeb\resources\views\cicilan.blade.php)
http://localhost:8000/cicilan/44
44 is the row ID
